# Universal link opening the wrong app (Facebook app)

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, deep-linking, ios-universal-links

we recently had a case on which some of our users reported normally tapping on a link in mobile iOS safari, and instead of being redirected to it in safari, it opened the Facebook app (as if it was a universal link relevant to Facebook - only, it wasn't).

The button our users clicked can be found in this domain (I'll use a fake domain for privacy reasons):

`www.aFakeDomain.com/profile.php`

and the link they clicked was this:

`<a href="profile.php?action=new">Click here</a>`

Now we do have an `apple-app-site-association` file under `www.aFakeDomain.com/apple-app-site-association` that looks like this:

```
{
    "applinks": {
        "apps": [],
        "details": [
            {
                "appID": "AAAAAAAAAA.com.aFakeDomain.app.ios",
                "paths": [ 
                    "/instant-link",
                    "/profile.php"
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
}
```

and our app Capabilities in iOS look like this:

```
applinks:*.aFakeDomain.com
applinks:aFakeDomain.com
```

We do use universal links that do open our native mobile app, but in that case our mobile app was not installed to our users phones.

This is the dialog our users receive:
[image]

Now how the heck was the Facebook app launched?
That's the weirdest thing ever..!

I appreciate any help,
thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never mind, that was caused by Facebook Pixel dispatching `SubscribedButtonClick`events with a call to `https://www.facebook.com/tr/?id=<OUR_ID>&ev=SubscribedButtonClick&...`

Resolved by adding:
`fbq('set', 'autoConfig', 'false', 'FB_PIXEL_ID')`
as instructed [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-pixel/using-the-pixel)

That was such a weird one, it took me hours to find out what was happening.

I'm leaving it here in hopes that it will spare wasted time from other devs out there.

Answer (score 0):

This is categorically impossible with Universal Links.

Without specific reproduction steps, or a screen capture of the behavior occurring, I'd file this under a user misreporting what they experienced.

Comment: but it's not just 1 user. We had 4-5 such reports just today.
I thought the same, but that is an issue, and I can't for the life of me reproduce it.

Comment: What happens next after the link is clicked? Is there a chance they hit a `fb://` custom URI scheme?

Comment: Nope they just hit the `<a href="profile.php?action=new">Click here</a>` button.

Then the Facebook app launches, and they can see their news feed.